# Releasing C Library (With ARC)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting

I am currently using `rtmpdump` as a C program inside my iOS application. However, I cannot seem to use it more than once without having to restart the application. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Relevant Code:

```
NSDictionary *details = [args objectAtIndex:0]; //rtmpe deatils
NSString *flvStore = [args objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *mp4Store = [args objectAtIndex:2];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar:) withObject:flvPath waitUntilDone:NO];
[self getFlashFile:details withFlvPathName:flvStore];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:flvPath]){
    NSNumber *filesize = 0;
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:flvPath traverseLink:NO];
    if(fileAttributes != nil){
        filesize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    }

    if([filesize longLongValue] > 1024){
        [self removeFlvWrapper:flvPath withMp4PathName:mp4Path andTitle:[thePid objectForKey:@"title"]];
    }
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:flvPath error:NULL];
}
```

---

```
- (void)getFlashFile:(NSDictionary *)details withFlvPathName:(NSString *)flvPath {
static char **rt_argv;
static int    rt_argc;

rt_argc = 16;
rt_argv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (rt_argc));
rt_argv[0] = "rtmpdump";
rt_argv[1] = (char *)[@"-r" UTF8String];
rt_argv[2] = (char *)[[details objectForKey:@"r"] UTF8String];
rt_argv[3] = (char *)[@"-a" UTF8String];
rt_argv[4] = (char *)[[details objectForKey:@"a"] UTF8String];
rt_argv[5] = (char *)[@"-f" UTF8String];
rt_argv[6] = (char *)[@"WIN 10,0,32,18" UTF8String];
rt_argv[7] = (char *)[@"-W" UTF8String];
rt_argv[8] = (char *)[[details objectForKey:@"W"] UTF8String];
rt_argv[9] = (char *)[@"-p" UTF8String];
rt_argv[10] = (char *)[[details objectForKey:@"p"] UTF8String];
rt_argv[11] = (char *)[@"-y" UTF8String];
rt_argv[12] = (char *)[[details objectForKey:@"y"] UTF8String];
rt_argv[13] = (char *)[@"-o" UTF8String];
rt_argv[14] = (char *)[flvPath UTF8String];
rt_argv[15] = (char *)[@"-q" UTF8String];

getStream(rt_argc, rt_argv);
finished = true;
}
```

You can also look at the [BigBadOwl repository under iPlayerFetch.m](https://github.com/BigBadOwl/iStreamer-Download-Manager/blob/master/iplayerFetch.m) to see similar code.

Comment: No more `[@"foo" UTF8String]` please! C has constant strings as well. `"foo"` is just fine.

Comment: What goes wrong if you try to do it twice? Why can't you seem to use it again?

Comment: I'm not sure... the two methods are in a separate class called DMDownloader which is created whenever the user clicks on a tablecell. I can confirm that the download does work as the UI hangs on getFlashFile. However, the second time a user clicks on the cell the UI does not hang and the temp file (flv) is not created in the temp directory as it is the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an alternative to rtmpdump in Objective-C. The code uses librtmp rather than rtmpdump, but was inspired from rtmpdump.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Darth, for a client i need to develop an on-the-fly rtmp converter. I would like to use an NSPipe paradigm, but I'm stuck with avformat_open_input. Can you give us more hints on howto write an Objective-C alternative to rtmpdump?